# How do 3D manuver gear works?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, transportation

After watching an anime, Attack on Titan I became annoyed by the devices used by those scouts tasked to protect civilians and the tall walls against the giants. I wonder how strong are these cables used to swing slim people around like a spiderman from Marvel? What is the tensile strength of those cable be because they seems to be able to incapacitate a 14m tall muscular giant without snapping and how does the hook works which seems to release on command before retracting into the dozen of batteries? Despite the event occurs 2000 years prior to modern day what mechanism could store pressurised air which seemingly used for launching the hooks at high speed?

Comment: If you are asking for in universe explanation of (commercial) fictional work, there is a dedicated stack exchange for that.

Comment: ISTR we had a question some time ago about the feasibility of such a system. It turned out the main problem is not the tensile strength (cables are ridiculously stronger than you'd think) or the weight or even the G-forces - it's human reaction time. Spider-man should be leaving big Spidey-shaped holes in Manhattan every couple of blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding how they Work:

Steel wire is stored inside the body (Maneuver Gear), installed in the lumbar area of the back. There are two axles, which revolve independently. The operating device has two triggers that launch the hooks, a lateral switch that aims the hooks and a brake. It also has a top piece where blades are put for combat. Thus the operating device also works as a sword's handle.

Also regarding how they managed to pressurize the gas; it's really simple! You can pressurize gas via a pump. When you pump tires or basketballs, you are increasing the pressure by pumping in more air. Therefore, you don't advanced technology and electricity. You only need simple Roman-Greek era engineering!

And lastly, this technology seems to only be used and known about by the people inside the walls. This is because of the The Beast Titan showed great interest in vertical maneuvering equipment, apparently having never encountered it before his meeting with Mike Zacharias, suggesting that the world beyond the Walls had been unaware of the existence of the device before this time.